# MaxConcurrentSessions is by default 10 or 100*processors

Tags: .net, wcf, performance

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379.aspx says value of maxConcurrentSessions is by default 10

where as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentsessions.aspx says its 100 times the processor count

Which statement is true? Is MSDN going nuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default configuration of throttling setting has changed between WCF 3.5 and WCF 4.0 so 10 was default value in WCF prior to 4.0 and 100 * processors count is till WCF 4.0.